# Issue using Matlab RK2 Code

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am trying to approximate the function:

$y'=-3y+6t+5$ with $y(-1)=2e^{3}-1$ and $h$ ranging from $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-1}$ on the interval $-1<t<2$.

I have written the code for the RK2 Method in Matlab as:

```
function [w, t, h] = rk2(dom, f, w0, h)

 % A naive implementation of RK2 method.
 % Inputs:
 % dom: time domain
 % f: an anonymous function defined by the RHS of original ODE IVP
 % y0: initial value
 % h: step size

T = diff(dom);
N = ceil(T/h);
h = T/N;

t = dom(1):h:dom(2);
w = zeros(N+1, 1);
w(1) = w0;

for i = 1:N
    k1 = h*f(t(i), w(i));
    k2 = h*f(t(i)+h/2, w(i)+k1/2);
    w(i+1) = w(i) + k2; % midpoint method
end

end
```

Writing the following in to the command window in Matlab:

```
[w,t,h]=rk2([-1:2], @(t,y) -3*y+6*t+5, 2*exp(3)-1, 10^(-1))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error using zeros
Size inputs must be scalar.

Error in rk2 (line 15)
w = zeros(N+1, 1);
```

Could someone please explain what I need to change in order to get this to work?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Replace `[-1:2]` with `[-1,2]`

Comment: Thank you @AVK, that worked, the issue I have now is when I use $h=10^{-4}$, I cannot see the initial $w_{0}$, $w_{1}$ & $w_{2}$ generated in the control window. I am using the RK2 to generate the initial values required for the AB3 method, so is there any way you know of I can view these?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You can run `disp(w(1:3))` to view the first 3 elements of  `w`.

Comment: that answered it, thank you very much!